# jQuery, get html of a whole element

Tags: jquery, html

I wish to get the entire html of a selected element not just it's contents. .html() uses javascripts innerHTML() method according to the documentation. 
HTML:

```
<div id="divs">
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `$('#divs:first').html();` will return just the paragraph element. I want to get the html for the whole element, like so:

```
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
```

I can't use .parent because this will return html of both child divs.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You can clone it to get the entire contents, like this:

```
var html = $("<div />").append($("#div1").clone()).html();
```

Or make it a plugin, most tend to call this "outerHTML", like this:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
  return jQuery('<div />').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
```

Then you can just call:

```
var html = $("#div1").outerHTML();
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it really sucks that jQuery doesn't implement its own method.

Comment: It is not perfect. In case HTML has a `script` tag the code from this tag will run when `append` is called. It might cause problems.

Answer (score 135):

Differences might not be meaningful in a typical use case, but using the standard DOM functionality

```
$("#el")[0].outerHTML
```

is about twice as fast as

```
$("<div />").append($("#el").clone()).html();
```

so I would go with:

```
/* 
 * Return outerHTML for the first element in a jQuery object,
 * or an empty string if the jQuery object is empty;  
 */
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
   return (this[0]) ? this[0].outerHTML : '';  
};
```

Comment: And if you just want the opening tag: `/<[^>]+>/.exec(elem[0].outerHTML)[0]`

Comment: I also like the defaulting to empty string instead of allowing null reference errors, nice and short and sweet and stable, thank you.  This works great for me.

Comment: Upvoting for standard DOM functionality, and twice as fast :)

Answer (score 38):

You can achieve that with just one line code that simplify that:

`$('#divs').get(0).outerHTML;`

As simple as that.

Comment: Because I'm in the situation with puppeteer, where jquery plugin is not very convenient, however this one line style is exactly suitable for puppeteer/phantomjs-like scrapping script.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get child itself and all of its decedents (children) with Jquery's Clone() method, just

```
var child = $('#div div:nth-child(1)').clone();  

var child2 = $('#div div:nth-child(2)').clone();
```

You will get this for first query as asked in question

```
<div id="div1">
     <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
```