# get html element as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery, get html of a whole element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element)

lets say I have:

```
<span>my span</span>
```

I would like have html as a string of this span

I use:

`var mySpan = $('span');`

what to do with the mySpan var to have as a result string `"<span>my span</span>"`

thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/HxU7B/2/.

---

UPDATE.

`mySpan[0].outerHTML` will take a previoulsy selected node and get a native `outerHTML` property. Since old Firefox versions doesn't have that property, we can use a bit of hack to get html - simply clone node to dummy `div` and then get this div's innerHTML: `$('<div/>').append(mySpan.clone()).html()`

Comment: psst. Igor, you will have better luck if you explain yourself, or post code in your answer.

Comment: @Fresheyeball No problem, sir :) I've slightly updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can't do that, but regular JavaScript DOM objects can:

```
var mySpanString = $('span').get(0).outerHTML;
```

Comment: 'jQuery can't do that' -1 this is just wrong!

Comment: Oh yeah?  Show me how to do it in jQuery without creating superfluous wrapper elements.  There is no way, you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you could use **outerHTML** or **clone -> append -> html()**

But here is another way to do it,

```
var nodeName = mySpan[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
var outerHtml = "<"+nodeName +">"+mySpan.html()+"</"+nodeName +">";
```