# Problems with targeting containing spans in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having a bit of strange trouble (I'm in datatables), targeting the containing spans of the page numbers. This is the html I'm running.

```
<span>
    <span class="target_me fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">1</span>
    <span class="target_me fg-button ui-button ui-state-default">2</span>
</span>
```

But when I put the click event on each number and call

```
alert($(this).parent().html())
```

It renders the entire code above, rather than just the inital span. This renders just the page number "2" or "1".

```
alert($(this).html())
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. You're asking the parent html, so you have the parent html. Can you be a little more precise in your question ? Maybe with the code attaching the event handlers ?

Comment: Look at this question, I think that you want to achieve similar thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612709/get-html-element-as-a-string

Comment: Sorry for not being as specific. I'm trying to get the span around the number -- ie, <span class="target_me fg-button ui-button ui-state-default"> -- instead of the container.

Comment: I still don't get it : wasn't my answer exactly what you were looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting exactly what you asked for. If you only want the tag for `this`, then try:

```
alert( $(this).wrap('<div>').parent().html() );
$(this).unwrap();
```

A shorter technique involves cloning outside of the DOM:

```
alert( $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html() );
```

Comment: HEheheh. That's a clever trick. You can also do `alert($(this)[0].outerHTML);`, but of course not all browsers support outerHTML, your trick is more compatible with old browsers.

Comment: This is great. Is there anyway I could make that a variable so I can use it in if else statements? var outerHTML =  $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html(); if ($(outerHTML).hasClass('ui-state-disabled')) { do something }

Comment: Well, yes. `.html()` outputs a string, which you can assign to a variable and use however you wish.

Comment: @aquinas and thank you for all your help (and if these are beginners questions!)!

Comment: @Blazemonger I guess I'm just having an error trying to run the .hasClass variable on the javascript variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. When you use `$(this).parent().html()` it gets the FIRST `span` in your code.(the one in CAPITAL case below)

```
<SPAN>
    <span class="target_me fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">1</span>
    <span class="target_me fg-button ui-button ui-state-default">2</span>
</SPAN>
```

and naturally it will print all the HTML inside it..

when you call `$(this).html()` it gets the SPAN that you clicked ON. In which case you get 1 or 2 based on which number you clicked..

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this :

```
alert(this.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).parent().html())
```

This is going to go to the `<span>` tag and alert the HTML inside of it.

`$(this).html()` when an item is clicked on will render the HTML inside the individual span, so 1 and 2, like intended.

What are you trying to achieve?