# How to get all children elements except one

Tags: jquery

I have the following content:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='inputCheckbox'/><strong>sdfsf</strong><p>dfsfsdsd</p>
```

From the elements above, I only need to get these elements when the checkbox are selected and omit the input element:

```
<strong>sdfsf</strong><p>dfsfsdsd</p>
```

My attempt:

```
$("#testPatternButton").on("click", function()
{
    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        alert($(this).parent().children().not("input").html()); // only the strong text shows up
    });
});
```

Comment: `html` only returns html content of the first matched element.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the first matched element, didn't know this.

Comment: Do you need to get the HTML string of those elements, or a collection of them you can reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `each()` and add up the `html()` contents.

```
$("#testPatternButton").on("click", function() {
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        var output = '';
        $(this).parent().children().not("input").each(function() {
            output = output + $(this).html();
        });
        alert(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: That does not show the <strong> tag though - at least not in Chrome

Comment: @mplungjan The `<strong>` tag isn't shown in the OP's original code either. What he needs is the html inside and this code does it.

Comment: He wanted `<strong>sdfsf</strong><p>dfsfsdsd</p>`

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think that's what he means but if you want such an output, use `.prop('outerHTML')` instead of `.html()`. The use of `.html()` suggests that he wants plain text only.

Comment: ahem, then .text() would make more sense

Comment: @mplungjan Well, he can change it any way he sees fit. Let him decide it.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it -- it uses [a common trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3614212/901048) to get the `.html()` of the input, then uses `.replace` to remove that string from the parent `.html()`.

```
$('input').on('click', function () {
    inputhtml = $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    allhtml = $(this).parent().html();
    str = allhtml.replace(inputhtml, '');
    alert(str);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnabj/

If, however, you really want a jQuery object of those elements instead of the HTML string, that's even easier:

```
$('input').on('click',function() {
    $var = $(this).siblings();
});
```

Comment: Siblings is the most elegant. Interestingly enough it does not seem to take anything before the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("#inputCheckbox").click(function(){
    var el = this;
    if (el.checked) {
        console.log(
            $(el).nextAll()
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/avXAb/)

```
$("#testPatternButton").on("click", function() {
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      $("#out").html($(this).parent().contents().not('input')); 
    });
});
```