# take only specific element out of content with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the `.html()` of an iFrame. But I only want the code of an specific element `<img id="picture">`. How can I get the HTML but have only the `<img id="picture">` with all parameters.

Something like:

```
$('#mydiv').find("iframe").contents().find("body").html(/*only get html of image here*/);
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery, get html of a whole element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element)

Comment: @isherwood I don't think so, because I just want the HTML of a specific element, not the outer HTML and the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var imgEl = $('#mydiv iframe #picture'),
    imgHTML = imgEl.prop('outerHTML');
```

[Simplified proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bR9B2/).