# Getting a HTML element DOM as string using javascript without child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, tostring

I was wondering if there was any method to get a html element / node without its children as a string. 

This question might seem like a duplicate of this question: [jQuery, get html of a whole element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element).
But i only want the html element itself as a string, without its children.

```
texts.push({title:'[#target, outerHTML]', value: $input[0].outerHTML});
texts.push({title:'[#target, $.html()]', value: $input.html()});

texts.push({title:'[#bigger_Target, outerHTML]', value: $('#bigger_Target')[0].outerHTML});
texts.push({title:'[#bigger_Target, $.html()]', value: $('#bigger_Target').html()});

texts.push({title:'[#target, DESIRED]', value: '<input class="test" data-type="text only" type="button" value="Test />"'});
texts.push({title:'[#bigger_Target, DESIRED]', value: '<div id="bigger_Target" />'});
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ttoom9hc/12/

**FIDDLE FROM OTHER POST:**
http://jsfiddle.net/u6avkvz0/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to clone it shallow with DOM's [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4), then get the `outerHTML` of that:

```
var element = $("selector for the element you want");
var html = element[0].cloneNode(false).outerHTML;
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/sitar/1) *(made my own, **wow** was that fiddle complex)*

---

Or with more jQuery: [Example](http://jsbin.com/sitar/5)

```
var html = $("selector for the element you want")
               .clone()
               .contents()
               .remove()
               .end()[0].outerHTML;
```

---

Note that the text inside the element is "child" content (specifically, one or more `Text` node children). If you want those, you'll need a loop. jQuery's `contents` can help there: [Example](http://jsbin.com/sitar/4/)

```
var html = $("selector for the element you want")
        .clone()
        .contents()
        .each(function() {
          if (this.nodeType !== 3) { // It's not a Text node...
            $(this).remove();        // ...nuke it
          }
        })
        .end()[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is perfect! The fiddle was that complex just to explain my request :P.