# Jquery each through <a> gives me href only

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have a simple menu

```
<div class="nav-container desktop">
    <a href="_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=klassen">One</a>
    <a href="_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=tw">Twp</a>
</div>
```

I am looping through this with jQuery each and then creating `<li>` tags with the complete `<a.../a>`.

```
$.each( $('.nav-container>a'), function(i, item){
        var menupunkt = '<li>' + item + '</li>'
        console.log(i, menupunkt);
    });
```

Examples: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwbgap, https://jsfiddle.net/86g44ssp/

In my console I see only the following

```
<li>http://xyz.ccom/_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=tw</li>"
```

[image]

Why don't I get the whole a? Because when I just print "item" I get the whole `<a.../a>`

Comment: What's `$('#replacemenu')`?

Comment: The console.log receives only the `href` since that's the return value of `HTMLElement#toString` on an anchor element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` or `this` represent a DOM element. You're casting it to string when you treat it as as string. You can use `item.outerHTML` - the string you're looking for - in place of `item`.

```js
     $.each( $('.nav-container>a'), function(i, item){
        var menupunkt = '<li>' + item.outerHTML + '</li>'
        console.log(i, menupunkt);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-container desktop">
    <a href="_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=klassen">One</a>
    <a href="_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=tw">Twp</a>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

Not sure if there's an advantage to it but I would prefer:

```
    $('.nav-container>a').each(function(i, item){
        var menupunkt = '<li>' + item.outerHTML + '</li>'
        console.log(i, menupunkt);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86g44ssp/3/), you just need to change

```
 var menupunkt = '<li>' + item + '</li>'
```

to

```
 var menupunkt = '<li>' + item.outerHTML + '</li>'
```

And there is no need to add extra wrapping or stuff, just get the HTML from outerHTML and you're done !

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.each( $('.nav-container>a'), function(i, item){
        var menupunkt = '<li>' + $(item).text() + '</li>'
        console.log(i, menupunkt);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-container desktop">
    <a href="_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=klassen">One</a>
    <a href="_index.php?page=_sub_papa&main=tw">Twp</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to access the outerHTML. I've included code from another SO answer:

[jQuery, get html of a whole element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element)

https://jsfiddle.net/86g44ssp/1/

The change I've made is here:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
  return jQuery('<div />').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};


... other code here ...

var menupunkt = '<li>' + $(item).outerHTML() + '</li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".nav-container a" ).wrap( "<li></li>" );
```

This is the fastest way to wrap **.nav-container a** inside list element.

While looping `$.each('.nav-container a', function(i,v) {});` each `<a>` are like object **NOT at TEXT**

if you want target specific elements use:

```
$.each('.nav-container a', function(i,v) {
var fullObject = $(this).html(),
link = $(this).attr('href'),
text = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, as you've suggested something without any context. This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by *type conversion*. When you do `'<li>' + item + '</li>'` the JavaScript runtime will try to convert `item` to a string. This is done "under the hood" by calling `toString()` method on the `item`, e.g. `item.toString()`. You can do forced *type conversion* by doing it explicit:

```
console.log(i, item.toString());
```