# jquery copy html from div and paste into a input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to copy the raw html with a div called #copy_history. I have managed to do it with the text works fine but i require the html as well.

The following does work but its grabbing the text not all the html:

**script:**

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    var text = $('#copy_history').text();
    $('.paste_history').val(text);
});
```

Comment: try this  var text = $('#copy_history').html();

Comment: Input element doesn't accept HTML, it can contain only plain text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, get html of a whole element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element)

Comment: @Teemu a textarea accepts html

Comment: @Pete [It doesn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). "_Permitted content: Character data_"

Comment: yes textarea does accept html so dont see why it should not work

Comment: @Teemu Any `input` that accepts text can accept markup... You cannot *render* HTML inside an `input`, but you may enter any text you want.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, maybe I've misunderstood the question ...

Comment: In what format are you wanting the HTML?, in plain text with TAG's etc.  Or it having bold / underline visible.

Comment: @Keith Well, reading the post carefully, there's "_trying to copy the raw html_" in the question, i.e. OP wants the markup, ( = "plain text with TAG's" I suppose). I missed this earlier, that's why the previous comments of mine.

Comment: @Teemu how do you think cms systems work then? - https://jsfiddle.net/L6xLjwaj/

Comment: Yes i require the html markup. i read that text area does except html?

Comment: the code is copying into the textarea with html but it is not saving html

Comment: @alwayslearning What you mean with "not saving"? The value doesn't show in the markup, when you're retrieving it afterwards? Change the value of the `value` attribute instead of `val()`. Textarea doesn't accept HTML, i.e. the value is always rendered as plain text.

Comment: `$(selector).html()` returns *text*.  The same as this comment is *text* but contains html, look, here: "<b>some<i>text</i></b>" - it's text, same as returned by `.html()`.   So you can put *text* in a textarea.

Comment: "but it is not saving html*" - there's **nothing** in the question about "saving" - please ask a new question and mark one of the answers as correct for the problem as *described in the question* - do not add-on extra, hidden, new "but now it does Y"

Comment: @freedomn-m well it depend, whats the point of copying html in a field that does not accept it. or does it. because if it doesnt then the answer should be you cant do this. as it is already part of my question " i need the html". which means i ned the html nothing less then that

Comment: As you wish new question hitting the forum due to nonsense politics and no one can agree if if a textarea holds html on being sent or not, so i make a new question askin the same thing again fine

Comment: Ok - looks like it depeonds on your definition of "html" - for most of us, "html" is "text that includes markup".  But perhaps you mean DOM nodes?

Comment: It's not "nonsense" - you ask a question, you get (multiple) answers that answer that question. If you then change that question, by adding "but now...", it's a *different* question and the existing answers, that people spent their time providing for you, now no longer answer the *new* question and what happens is other people come to the question and read the new question and see the answers for the old question and go "that doesn't answer the [new] question", not realising it's new and *downvote* the answers.  Which is unfair and frankly, a bit rude to those that spent their time helping you

Comment: Is this what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/pzhc9f29/ ?  Or did you already get passed this bit?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    var text = $('#copy_history').html();
    $('.paste_history').val(text);
});
```

Hope this will work..

Comment: Don't put html in both.  For $(.past_history) keep it as val().

Comment: ok it works but it does not save the html? i will check the anti injection, might be the problem xss

Answer (score 4):

See [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and/or [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

Grab the markup *inside* a given element:

```js
$('#copy').on('click', function() {
  $('#input').val($('#sample').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sample">Here's some <b>markup</b></div>

<label for="input">Input</label>
<input type="text" id="input"/>

<button id="copy">Copy sample markup</button>
```

Grab the markup inside and *including* the given element:

```js
$('#copy').on('click', function() {
  $('#input').val($('<div/>').append($('#sample').clone()).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sample">Here's some <b>markup</b></div>

<label for="input">Input</label>
<input type="text" id="input"/>

<button id="copy">Copy sample markup</button>
```

Comment: To include given markup element, this would be easier: `$('#input').val($('#sample').prop('outerHTML'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try `append()` insteal of `val()`:

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    var text = $('#copy_history');
    $('.paste_history').append(text);
});
```