# Use Javascript dom instead of jQuery element selector (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element variable:

```
element = '<div class="c-element js-element">Something Here</div>';
```

Needed to select this element like:

```
$(element)
```

it returns no string return like:

```
n.fn.init [div.c-element.js-element, context: div.c-element.js-element] // and more
```

How can I select a given string element in javascript dom like jQuery selector?

Comment: There aren't jQuery selectors (for the most part), those are *CSS* selectors (look up `querySelector`)

Comment: Do you which to create the element manually, or just get an element from the dom using `document.querySelector`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, get html of a whole element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element)

Comment: there is given element fully don't have class name or id, it is using inside a function.

document.querySelector(element):

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector`

Comment: @NitinSawant i need to use javascript dom, without jquery

Comment: Please elaborate on *"I need to use javascript dom, without jquery"* - your question is tagged [jquery] and you have used jquery in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`$(element).get(0)` will return the DOM element. 
Also you could use native bindings:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.classList.add('c-element', 'js-element');
element.innerHTML = 'Something here'
```