# Get HTML of anchor tag with onclick event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the html of entire anchor tag but it returns only `<span>` tag html.What am I missing ?

```
getDetails = function (ord_id) {
                var $a = $('a[data-ord_id^=' + ord_id + ']');
                console.log($a.html());            
};    

 <a aria-role="button" class="boxSizing" data-businesslocaltime="05/05/2020 11:32 PM" data-business_id="1" data-completedstage="0" data-deferdue="5/5/2020 11:17:27 PM" data-ord_id="462724" data-refnum="R60152" data-timestamp="5/5/2020 10:32:40 PM" onclick="getDetails('462724','0');" role="listitem"><span class="material-icons boxSizing"></span><span class="ordtype boxSizing">Pick Up</span><span class="ordtime boxSizing"> placed @ 11:32 PM, May 05 2020</span></a>
```

### Result

```
<span class="material-icons boxSizing"></span><span class="ordtype boxSizing"></span><span class="ordtime boxSizing"> placed @ 04:12 PM, May 05 2020</span>
```

Comment: I hope help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614212/jquery-get-html-of-a-whole-element There ir a useful fix.

Comment: Thanks Ronald for pointing out at right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Did the trick,

```
var $a = $('[data-ord_id^=' + ord_id + ']');
console.log($a.get(0).outerHTML);
```